# SQL Query to return a set that doesn't fall between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a 'borrower' table that is joined to a 'loan' table. I am trying to return all borrowers that DO NOT have a loan on a certain day. This is the code I have so far and I have hit a bit of a wall as this seems to be the way to go about this, admittedly I am quite new to SQL and I may be far off but any help would be greatly appreciated. I return all the borrowers using this code, rather than 60 or so that I should. Thankyou!

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.cardno, b.fname ||' '|| b.lname AS "BORROWER NAME"
FROM borrower b
JOIN loan l ON b.cardno = l.cardno
WHERE '01/SEP/05' NOT BETWEEN l.dateout AND l.datein
ORDER BY b.cardno;
```

Using a link provided to some info I have managed to reduce my return set by a fair bit but still returning too many borrowers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.cardno, b.fname ||' '|| b.lname AS "BORROWER NAME"
FROM borrower b
JOIN loan l ON b.cardno = l.cardno
where l.dateout < '01/SEP/05'
and l.datein > '01/SEP/05'
ORDER BY b.cardno;
```

Comment: Can you verify if your WHERE clause is effective? What if you remove the WHERE clause? 
Is the date format correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query will look for all loans on any other day; so it would only exclude anyone who *only* had a book on that day. If you changed the first line to:

```
SELECT b.cardno, b.fname ||' '|| b.lname AS "BORROWER NAME", l.dateout, l.datein
```

you would see all of the loans not on that day; so all (or almost all) borrowers, but not all loans.

But '01/SEP/05' is not a date; you are relying on implicit conversion using your session settings, which is not a good idea, and you could end up with values you don't expect - which might mean the date matching isn't working as you expect anyway. It's better to use `to_date()` with a suitable format mask, and preferably 4-digit years; or a date literal like `DATE '2005-09-01'`.

You could use `not exists`, with something like:

```
SELECT b.cardno, b.fname ||' '|| b.lname AS "BORROWER NAME"
FROM borrower b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT null
  FROM loan l
  WHERE l.cardno = b.cardno
  AND DATE '2005-09-01' BETWEEN l.dateout AND l.datein
)
ORDER BY b.cardno;
```

Even there the date match might not quite work, if your date in/out has the actual time rather than midnight. Any loans made after midnight on your target date would be excluded. So instead you could make that:

```
  AND l.dateout < DATE '2005-09-01' + 1
  AND l_datein >= DATE '2005-09-01'
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, very informative. Yeah I am new to all this as you can tell and struggle around the date stuff a lot, thankyou again!